# How do I remove URL parameters from an apache 301 redirect?

Tags: apache

I'm trying to hard code a redirect on my site from a category based URL to a fixed URL.

The url structure is :

```
http://www.mysite.com/my-category-c-17_12.html
```

And I'm trying to redirect that to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/my-static-category.php
```

Using the following redirect in my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /my-category-c-17_12.html http://www.mysite.com/my-static-category.php
```

I end up with:

```
http://www.mysite.com/my-static-category.php?cpath=17_12
```

Below my redirect, I also have the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I'm not sure if that is what is causing it or not.  Basically I want a way to strip the parameters from the redirected URL.  Does anyone know how to deal with that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a global rewrite (as per Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's suggestion)..
Instead of using the Redirect directive, just use RewriteRule. Something like (in full):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Limited redirects
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} my-category-c-17_12.html$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} my-category-c-17_13.html$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} my-category-c-17_14.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ $1.php [R=301,L]

# Other rewrites
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ index.php?cPath=$2 [QSA,L]
```

You could then add other URLs to the RewriteCond to allow more URLs to be redirected.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `mod_rewrite` then why not just use it?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm only looking to rewrite specific URLs, not all URLs, so I don't want to change the behavior of the rest of the site.  And this need to be a 301 because I'm just trying to keep old links in tact.